# scrollTop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is floating meny div xwiki-controls working when

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

or `$(document).scroll(function() {
            var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();`

but dont work like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nav = $('.xwiki_controls');
    var isFixed = false;
    $('#parag').scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $('#parag').scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > 250;
        ...
```

Comment: are you closing the `$(document).ready`? check for errors in console.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: What are the error messages, if any, are you getting? Check in your browser console / error viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample of code which I have tested. Hope it will help you.

This is used to stick the div on top.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var p = $("#stop").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(p<$(window).scrollTop()){
            console.log("div reached");
            $("#stop").css({position:"fixed",top:0});
        }
        else{
            console.log("div out");
            $("#stop").css({position:"static"});
        }

    })
});
```

Comment: this code work great but, how i can limit floating only in 1 div,not in all window?

Comment: @user2622964 I am not clear about your question? Do you mean limit floating for example in the middle of the window? Can you make you a bit more clear?

Comment: @user2622964 can you provide example? any site where you see that.

Comment: Yes limit floating in the middle of div.