# Div stops at the top when scrolling

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a div change class to fixed when it reach the top of the page.

I have this **JavaScript** code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var top = 200;
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y >= top) {
            // if so, add the fixed class
            $('#kolonne-v').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            // otherwise remove it
            $('#kolonne-v').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: this code only executes 1 time...you need to use an event like scroll `.on('scroll', handler)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrollTop not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883031/scrolltop-not-working)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883031/scrolltop-not-working/17884188#17884188 may have the answer you may want.

Comment: @abc123JavaScript is new to me. Can you provide an eksample?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ is the documentation, i'll post an answer here in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/ZTkLg/8/)

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var top = 200; 
    //this should be the offset of the top of your div 
    //which can be found by doing the following line

    //var top = $("#kolonne-v").offset().top;

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if (top <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            // if so, add the fixed class
            $('#kolonne-v').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            // otherwise remove it
            $('#kolonne-v').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    })
});
```

***Description***

*This uses the jquery `.on('scroll', handler)` method, [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/).  The basic principal is that on `document.ready` you set the scroll point when your div becomes fixed to the top.  Then you setup an `.on('scroll', handler)` event that triggers whenever the window is scrolled in.  If the user scrolls to your point you add the `fixed` CSS class.*

Comment: @JonatanKnudsen let me know if you need any more information, have a good day.